# set NODE_ENV=test causes jest unit test to fail

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jestjs

In my package.json I added `"test": "set NODE_ENV=test && jest --watch"` to set up my unit tests.

After troubleshooting for a long time to find out why I get this error message:

```
{import { configure } from 'enzyme';
        ^
SyntaxError: Unexpected token {
```

I found that by removing `set NODE_ENV=test &&` I resolve the issue. I am now thinking that it must have something to do with the test config instead:

```
"babel": {
    "env": {
      "test": {
        "presets": [
          [
            "next/babel",
            {
              "preset-env": {
                "modules": "commonjs"
              }
            }
          ],
          "@babel/preset-env"
        ],
        "plugins": [
          "transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"
        ]
      }
    }
  }
```

Adding `"transform-es2015-modules-commonjs"` and `@babel/preset-env` has been suggested in similar posts, but I am not confident it is related to the issue.

I installed [cross-env](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-env) and added it: `"test": "cross-env NODE_ENV=test jest --watch"` which works perfectly. I am on a **windows machine**, by the way.

How is cross-env compiling my commands differently than `set NODE_ENV=test && jest --watch` ??

Comment: Did you found the solution and answer to this question ?